# iText set cell's height

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I am using a java version of this library and can't figure out how to set the cell's height. When I use cell.setFixedHeight() and passing any number less that 18 the content dissapears in output PDF file. Why?
Thank you

Comment: you can look this url:[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279646/how-to-set-height-of-pdfptable-in-itextsharp/41162147#41162147)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check whether  the width and height given for document is not exceeds.

> Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 60, 60, 120, 80);

and for cell height you have to give in float value
for e.g

> Cell.setFixedHeight(45f);

I hope this will help you to proceed further :-)

Answer (score 1):

The checked answer to this question is old.
New answer to this problem is the

`cell.setMinHeight(10f);`

If you want to give a cell a specific height or width, after creating the cell you can set minHeight or minWidth with a float value.

Comment: Please expand your answer and explain how it solves the post. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer