# can iTextSharp place element in vertical without breaking the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I am trying to make pdf to look like this

[image]

First column it fill until the end of the page then go to next column.
When the page is fill then break into new page.
Its that possible with ITextSharp ? Or is there any simple plugin that would work better for my current situation.

I try using PdfpTable but i don't know how i can get information about my last element in the column then jump to next column.

Comment: Do you really want a table here? Or would `ColumnText` be of use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a basic simple `PdfPTable` the answer is no. A table's height is determined by the sum of each row's height which is determined by the max height of each cell in that row.

However, in your case you want to know the table's height in the *first column* which is *before* the table's row's cells have been completed. If iText actually answered the question of the row's height in the first column before further cells were added, new cells in that row would have to be forced to fit and could get cutoff.

That said, if you can [fix every cell's height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25287384/231316) to a value you feel comrotable with you can use [general transposition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4492678/231316) to swap rows for columns.