# How to make a table cell show with empty/whitespace content?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I fill ITextSharp tables dynamically from variables that may hold empty string. When all the values in the row are empty, the row collapses to same minimum height (`SpacingBefore` + `SpacingAfter` if I understand it well). While I understand those cells should usually be hidden, in this case I would like to make those cells visible without writing anything in them. I tried to substitute the empty strings by `Chunk.NEWLINE;`, but it didn't work.

Comment: does the package not have a standard row height attribute you can assign to?

Comment: @Takarii: you're right and I'm dumb. [FixedHeight](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25287384/1801588) solves the problem. Would you like to expand your comment to an answer, so that this question is not "unanswered"?

Comment: I would, but that wouldn't be right (I guessed, and im no reputation horder). Instead, I will mark this as a duplicate and link the reference post. I recommend you upvote the answer give in that post to give credit to the original poster instead :)

Comment: @Takarii: yeah, that's even better. I already upvoted it.